# Issue deleting row from database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So this seems pretty simple but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have my database delete command:

```
public boolean deleteContact(String rowId) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

I also should mention that I am displaying the database in a listview. So when the user clicks on an item they are presented with a "OK" and a "Delete" option.

When they hit delete this is the command I'm using:

```
db.open();
db.deleteContact("Apple Recipe");
db.close();
dialog.dismiss();
```

I keep getting a force close issue that says:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ner "Recipe":syntax error
(code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM list WHERE item=Apple Recipe
```

I'm probably doing something stupid so maybe fresh eyes will help.

Comment: Did you try to add `'` in your delete statement ? Like this : `return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId + "'", null) > 0;`

Comment: OH MY GOSH... That worked! I knew It'd be something simple! Thank you!

Comment: Let me mark it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'` in your delete statement, like this :

```
return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId + "'", null) > 0;
```

Or, as mentionned by other posters, you can use separate parameters :

```
String whereString = KEY_ROWID + "= ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] { rowId };
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, whereString, whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

the delete method for a contentResolver takes, a Uri, a "where" string, and an args string.
and row id is most likely an int

So it should be something like this
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"rowId = ? ", row_id_number);

or if you are looking to match some field such as "recipe" which is a string then.
assuming the field name is recipe:
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "recipe = ?", "Apple Recipe");

Answer (score 1):

To be honest you should be using:

```
return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{rowId}) > 0;
```

Its more of a safety thing to do with escaping the values to make sure no SQL is in the string that could execute