# Unable to delete specific row in sqlite when string contains "-"

Tags: android

I have simple listview which displays name and number (This data actually from database). When i try to delete its working fine (for number field as "123456") but the problem is unable to delete some list items which has the number field as "888-888-00"

Here added my code... Plesae help me out....,

DatabaseHelpher.java

```
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_NUMBER = "number";

public void deleteContacts(String name, String number){
    //Raw Query wont work for Deletion
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    System.out.println("deleted number: "+number+"name: "+name);
    String deleteQuery = "Delete from "+CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME+" where "+KEY_NUMBER+" = "+number;
    //db.rawQuery("Delete from "+CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME+" where "+KEY_NUMBER+" = "+number, null);
    db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    db.close();
}
```

MainActivity.java

Inside oncreate() method contains,

```
selectedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            final HashMap<String, String> toDelete = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            deleteDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");
            deleteDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this '"+toDelete.get("name")+"' Contact?");

            deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dataBaseHelpher.deleteContacts(toDelete.get("name"), toDelete.get("number"));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    updateList();
                }
            });
            deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            deleteDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the problem on deleting

Comment: Try using prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue deleting row from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690163/issue-deleting-row-from-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround your number with quotes 'cause '888-888-888' is a string not an integer.

```
String deleteQuery = "delete from " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME + " where " + KEY_NUMBER + " = '" + number + "'";
```

It's better to use a preprared statement, like this.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("delete from ? where ? = ?");
stmt.bindString(1, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
stmt.bindString(2, KEY_NUMBER );
stmt.bindString(3, number);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Nice, which solution did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code-

```
db.delete("Your Table Name", "KEY_NUMBER = " + number, null);
```